# Breaking POST request into parts in Yesod

Tags: haskell, post, yesod

I'm struggling to split a POST response (multipart) apart, what should be used to put the contents of some files sent to the Yesod server into a database (after some further processing). My current code:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LZ
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LC
...
processLines :: String -> [String] -> String
processLines delim (l:rest) = do
    case l of
        delim -> ""
        _     -> l ++ "\n" ++ processLines delim rest

processFile :: [String] -> String
processFile (delim:some:other:line:txt) = processLines delim txt

postImpexR :: SystemsId -> Handler RepPlain
postImpexR sysid = do
    wr <- waiRequest
    bss <- lift $ requestBody wr $$ consume
    let file = LZ.fromChunks bss
    return $ RepPlain $ toContent $ processFile $ map LC.unpack $ LC.lines file
```

Edit: Managed to fix one problem, seems I'm on the way to understand handlers. What's the problem with the types here?? Is there a more elegant way to get this done than this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for multipart support, that's built into Yesod, there's no need to resort to manual parsing. Consider using [fileField](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/2012-12-11/yesod-form/Yesod-Form-Fields.html#v%3afileField) or [lookupFile](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/2012-12-11/yesod-core/Yesod-Request.html#v%3alookupFile).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems I have most trouble getting correct information.

Comment: OK, but when I use fInfo <- lookupFiles in the handler, it wants an additional text argument. If I append "filename" (as the POST parameter name is), I get an empty list.

Comment: I can't explain why that's happening without knowing the details of the request, but file uploads should be fully supported. If something's wrong, then you should file a bug report.

Comment: OK, found a problem with the request generator, my fault. Thanks a lot.